# util.inherits - how to call method of super on instance?

Tags: node.js, inheritance

I'm playing with `util.inherits` [method from node.js](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) and can't seem to get the desired behavior.

```
var util = require("util");

function A() {
  this.name = 'old';
}

A.prototype.log =  function(){
  console.log('my old name is: '+ this.name);
};

function B(){
  A.call(this);
  this.name = 'new';
}

util.inherits(B, A);

B.prototype.log = function(){
  B.super_.prototype.log();
  console.log('my new name is: ' + this.name);
}

var b = new B();
b.log();
```

The result is:

```
my old name is: undefined 
my new name is: new
```

However what I would like is:

```
my old name is: new 
my new name is: new
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here's how to achieve what you are looking for:

```
B.prototype.log = function () {
  B.super_.prototype.log.apply(this);

  console.log('my new name is: ' + this.name);
};
```

This ensures the `this` context is the instance of `B` instead of being `B.super_.prototype` I suppose.

Comment: Other way: B.super_.prototype.log.call(this);

Comment: Btw the call is better choice .. http://jsperf.com/function-calls-direct-vs-apply-vs-call-vs-bind/6

Comment: I prefer to make use of `this` keyword : `this.constructor.super_.prototype.log.call(this)`, so that you don't need to use the class name again in the method

Comment: @kit using `this` keyword does work but there is one side effect. Example: `C` inherits `B` inherits `A` and they all have a `log` function.  `this.constructor.super_` will always return `B`. So if `B` wants to call a function in `A` and uses `this.constructor.super_.prototype.log.call(this)` `B` will just call it's self.

Comment: how about make use of `prototype` directly?
`Object.getPrototypeOf(prototype).log.call(this)`, so that you do not need to find super_.

Comment: if you meant `Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype).log.call(this)`, yes, that would work too.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to call method of super through `prototype chain` instead of `constructor chain` like following.

```
var prototype = C.prototype;

prototype.log = function() {
  Object.getPrototypeOf(prototype).log.call(this)

  // or old style
  prototype.__proto__.log.call(this)
}
```

They are all accessing prototype object of super class, but using `prototype chain` might be better than `constructor.super_.prototype` of `constructor chain`.

because usually I hide `protected`, `private` methods in separated files and under a `prototype` folder. Only `public` methods are with the `constructor` function in the `same scope`. In addition, to make them easy to move around different classes. All of them are named as `prototype.method = function() {...}`, so most of them can only access the prototype object.

Or it would be appreciated to know any benefit to go through `constructor chain`? This is why I found this post.